# Searching for nodes from another site in a multisite installation

Tags: nodes, search, multi-sites

I am trying to have the search function of a www.site.com return also nodes from site.com/somethingelse. Is there any way I can achieve this?

I prefer not to use Solr.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that easy enough with Google Custom Search, e.g:

1. http://www.google.com/cse
2. http://drupal.org/project/google_cse

Basically can search a range of selected sites from one interface, using the power of Google search.